# facetFilter not returning expected filtered response from an API request

Tags: algolia

I'm trying to filter Nintendo's Algolia response so that I would only get games with dlcType that are NOT 'Individual', but for some reason its not working for me. However, if I facetFilter a field that contains an array (e.g. availability field) it works fine.

Here is my request:

```
{
  "requests": [{
  "indexName":"store_game_en_us", 
  "params":"query=overcooked&hitsPerPage=5&page=0&analytics=false&facetFilters=%22dlcType%3A-Individual%22"
  }]
}
```

Here is the response/unfiltered i get:

```
    {
    "results": [
        {
            "hits": [
                {
                    "availability": [
                        "Available now"
                    ],
                    "classindDescriptors": null,
                    "classindRating": "L",
                    "corePlatforms": [
                        "Nintendo Switch"
                    ],
                    "demoNsuid": null,
                    "editions": [
                        "Digital"
                    ],
                    "esrbDescriptors": [
                        "Mild Cartoon Violence"
                    ],
                    "esrbRating": "E",
                    "genres": [
                        "Simulation",
                        "Multiplayer",
                        "Strategy"
                    ],
                    "nsoFeatures": [
                        "Online Play",
                        "Save Data Cloud"
                    ],
                    "playModes": [
                        "TV mode",
                        "Tabletop mode",
                        "Handheld mode"
                    ],
                    "playerCount": "4+",
                    "smecDescriptors": [
                        "Mild Cartoon Violence"
                    ],
                    "smecRating": "A",
                    "softwareDeveloper": "Ghost Town Games and Team17",
                    "softwarePublisher": "Team17",
                    "createdAt": "2021-11-12T20:52:15.000Z",
                    "collectionPriceRange": "$10 - $19.99",
                    "description": "Enjoy hundreds of levels of cooperative cooking chaos across increasingly perilous and obscure kitchens. Overcooked! Goes Online For the first time ever, online multiplayer has been fully integrated into Overcooked! Revisit your favourite kitchens from t…",
                    "exclusive": false,
                    "featuredProduct": false,
                    "nsuid": "70010000029237",
                    "platinumPoints": null,
                    "platform": "Nintendo Switch",
                    "platformCode": "NINTENDO_SWITCH",
                    "price": {
                        "regPrice": 39.99,
                        "finalPrice": 19.99,
                        "salePrice": 19.99
                    },
                    "priceRange": "$10 - $19.99",
                    "productImage": "ncom/en_US/games/switch/o/overcooked-all-you-can-eat-switch/hero",
                    "franchises": [],
                    "title": "Overcooked! All You Can Eat",
                    "releaseDateDisplay": null,
                    "sku": "7100029237",
                    "updatedAt": "2022-05-03T19:19:56.000Z",
                    "url": "/store/products/overcooked-all-you-can-eat-switch/",
                    "urlKey": "overcooked-all-you-can-eat-switch",
                    "visibleInSearch": true,
                    "topLevelCategory": "Games",
                    "topLevelCategoryCode": "GAMES",
                    "topLevelFilters": [
                        "Deals"
                    ],
                    "type": "game",
                    "dlcType": null,
                    "contentRatingCode": "E",
                    "hasDlc": false,
                    "objectID": "7100029237"
                },
                {
                    "availability": [
                        "Available now"
                    ],
                    "classindDescriptors": null,
                    "classindRating": "L",
                    "corePlatforms": [
                        "Nintendo Switch"
                    ],
                    "demoNsuid": null,
                    "editions": [
                        "Digital"
                    ],
                    "esrbDescriptors": null,
                    "esrbRating": "E",
                    "genres": [
                        "Strategy",
                        "Party",
                        "Simulation"
                    ],
                    "nsoFeatures": [
                        "Online Play",
                        "Save Data Cloud"
                    ],
                    "playModes": [
                        "TV mode",
                        "Tabletop mode",
                        "Handheld mode"
                    ],
                    "playerCount": "4+",
                    "smecDescriptors": null,
                    "smecRating": "A",
                    "softwareDeveloper": null,
                    "softwarePublisher": "Team17",
                    "createdAt": "2021-11-12T20:59:37.000Z",
                    "collectionPriceRange": "$20 - $39.99",
                    "description": "Out of the frying pan, into the fire... You’ve saved the world from the Ever Peckish. Now a new threat has arisen and it’s time to get back in the kitchen to stave off the hunger of The Unbread! ONLINE/LOCAL MULTIPLAYER MADNESS - You’ll knead to work tog…",
                    "exclusive": false,
                    "featuredProduct": false,
                    "nsuid": "70010000003402",
                    "platinumPoints": null,
                    "platform": "Nintendo Switch",
                    "platformCode": "NINTENDO_SWITCH",
                    "price": {
                        "regPrice": 24.99,
                        "finalPrice": 24.99,
                        "salePrice": null
                    },
                    "priceRange": "$20 - $39.99",
                    "productImage": "ncom/en_US/games/switch/o/overcooked-2-switch/hero",
                    "franchises": [],
                    "title": "Overcooked! 2",
                    "releaseDateDisplay": null,
                    "sku": "7100003402",
                    "updatedAt": "2022-05-06T16:57:52.000Z",
                    "url": "/store/products/overcooked-2-switch/",
                    "urlKey": "overcooked-2-switch",
                    "visibleInSearch": true,
                    "topLevelCategory": "Games",
                    "topLevelCategoryCode": "GAMES",
                    "topLevelFilters": [],
                    "type": "game",
                    "dlcType": null,
                    "contentRatingCode": "E",
                    "hasDlc": false,
                    "objectID": "7100003402"
                },
                {
                    "availability": [
                        "Available now"
                    ],
                    "classindDescriptors": null,
                    "classindRating": "L",
                    "corePlatforms": [
                        "Nintendo Switch"
                    ],
                    "demoNsuid": null,
                    "editions": [
                        "Digital"
                    ],
                    "esrbDescriptors": [
                        "Mild Cartoon Violence"
                    ],
                    "esrbRating": "E",
                    "genres": [
                        "Strategy",
                        "Party",
                        "Simulation"
                    ],
                    "nsoFeatures": [
                        "Save Data Cloud"
                    ],
                    "playModes": [
                        "TV mode",
                        "Tabletop mode",
                        "Handheld mode"
                    ],
                    "playerCount": "4+",
                    "smecDescriptors": [
                        "Mild Cartoon Violence"
                    ],
                    "smecRating": "A",
                    "softwareDeveloper": null,
                    "softwarePublisher": "Team17",
                    "createdAt": "2021-11-12T20:52:10.000Z",
                    "collectionPriceRange": "$10 - $19.99",
                    "description": "Working as a team, you and your fellow chefs must prepare, cook and serve up a variety of tasty orders before the baying customers storm out in a huff. Sharpen your knives and dust off your chef’s whites, there isn’t mushroom for error and the steaks are…",
                    "exclusive": false,
                    "featuredProduct": false,
                    "nsuid": "70010000000883",
                    "platinumPoints": null,
                    "platform": "Nintendo Switch",
                    "platformCode": "NINTENDO_SWITCH",
                    "price": {
                        "regPrice": 19.99,
                        "finalPrice": 19.99,
                        "salePrice": null
                    },
                    "priceRange": "$10 - $19.99",
                    "productImage": "ncom/en_US/games/switch/o/overcooked-special-edition-switch/hero",
                    "franchises": [],
                    "title": "Overcooked Special Edition",
                    "releaseDateDisplay": null,
                    "sku": "7100000883",
                    "updatedAt": "2022-05-03T21:23:00.000Z",
                    "url": "/store/products/overcooked-special-edition-switch/",
                    "urlKey": "overcooked-special-edition-switch",
                    "visibleInSearch": true,
                    "topLevelCategory": "Games",
                    "topLevelCategoryCode": "GAMES",
                    "topLevelFilters": [],
                    "type": "game",
                    "dlcType": null,
                    "contentRatingCode": "E",
                    "hasDlc": false,
                    "objectID": "7100000883"
                },
                {
                    "availability": [
                        "Available now"
                    ],
                    "classindDescriptors": null,
                    "classindRating": "L",
                    "corePlatforms": [
                        "Nintendo Switch"
                    ],
                    "demoNsuid": null,
                    "editions": [
                        "Digital"
                    ],
                    "esrbDescriptors": null,
                    "esrbRating": "E",
                    "genres": null,
                    "nsoFeatures": null,
                    "playModes": [
                        "TV mode",
                        "Tabletop mode",
                        "Handheld mode"
                    ],
                    "playerCount": null,
                    "smecDescriptors": null,
                    "smecRating": "A",
                    "softwareDeveloper": null,
                    "softwarePublisher": "Team17",
                    "createdAt": "2021-11-12T23:40:55.000Z",
                    "collectionPriceRange": "$10 - $19.99",
                    "description": "Cook alone or with friends as you travel through the onion kingdom and master over 20 recipes across 130 sizzling levels.  Overcooked! 2: Gourmet Edition The Overcooked! 2 Gourmet Edition gives players every course of award-winning chaotic cooking fun wi…",
                    "exclusive": false,
                    "featuredProduct": false,
                    "nsuid": "70070000010201",
                    "platinumPoints": null,
                    "platform": "Nintendo Switch",
                    "platformCode": "NINTENDO_SWITCH",
                    "price": {
                        "regPrice": 48.49,
                        "finalPrice": 12.12,
                        "salePrice": 12.12
                    },
                    "priceRange": "$10 - $19.99",
                    "productImage": "ncom/en_US/dlc/switch-dlc/overcooked-2-dlc/rom-bundle/overcooked-2-gourmet-edition/image",
                    "franchises": [],
                    "title": "Overcooked! 2 - Gourmet Edition",
                    "releaseDateDisplay": null,
                    "sku": "7700010201",
                    "updatedAt": "2022-05-06T17:49:37.000Z",
                    "url": "/store/products/overcooked-2-gourmet-edition-switch/",
                    "urlKey": "overcooked-2-gourmet-edition-switch",
                    "visibleInSearch": true,
                    "topLevelCategory": "Games",
                    "topLevelCategoryCode": "GAMES",
                    "topLevelFilters": [
                        "Deals",
                        "Games with DLC"
                    ],
                    "type": "game",
                    "dlcType": "ROM Bundle",
                    "contentRatingCode": "E",
                    "hasDlc": true,
                    "objectID": "7700010201"
                },
                {
                    "availability": [
                        "Available now"
                    ],
                    "classindDescriptors": null,
                    "classindRating": "L",
                    "corePlatforms": [
                        "Nintendo Switch"
                    ],
                    "demoNsuid": null,
                    "editions": [
                        "Digital"
                    ],
                    "esrbDescriptors": null,
                    "esrbRating": "E",
                    "genres": null,
                    "nsoFeatures": null,
                    "playModes": [
                        "Handheld mode",
                        "Tabletop mode",
                        "TV mode"
                    ],
                    "playerCount": null,
                    "smecDescriptors": null,
                    "smecRating": "A",
                    "softwareDeveloper": null,
                    "softwarePublisher": "Team17",
                    "createdAt": "2021-11-12T22:17:33.000Z",
                    "collectionPriceRange": "$0 - $9.99",
                    "description": "Overcooked! 2 Carnival of Chaos invites players to a celebration of all things cooking, co-op and chaos! This colourful new DLC will put players to the test as you take on combo meals and that kitchen essential, the canon! Canons!  An unconventional kitc…",
                    "exclusive": false,
                    "featuredProduct": false,
                    "nsuid": "70050000011524",
                    "platinumPoints": null,
                    "platform": "Nintendo Switch",
                    "platformCode": "NINTENDO_SWITCH",
                    "price": {
                        "regPrice": 5.99,
                        "finalPrice": 5.99,
                        "salePrice": null
                    },
                    "priceRange": "$5 - $9.99",
                    "productImage": "ncom/en_US/dlc/switch-dlc/overcooked-2-dlc/individual/overcooked-2-carnival-of-chaos/image",
                    "franchises": [],
                    "title": "Overcooked! 2 - Carnival of Chaos",
                    "releaseDateDisplay": null,
                    "sku": "7500011524",
                    "updatedAt": "2022-05-06T22:25:01.000Z",
                    "url": "/store/products/overcooked-2-carnival-of-chaos-70050000011524-switch/",
                    "urlKey": "overcooked-2-carnival-of-chaos-70050000011524-switch",
                    "visibleInSearch": true,
                    "topLevelCategory": "Games",
                    "topLevelCategoryCode": "GAMES",
                    "topLevelFilters": [
                        "DLC"
                    ],
                    "type": "game",
                    "dlcType": "Individual",
                    "contentRatingCode": "E",
                    "hasDlc": true,
                    "objectID": "7500011524"
                }
            ],
            "nbHits": 11,
            "page": 0,
            "nbPages": 3,
            "hitsPerPage": 5,
            "exhaustiveNbHits": true,
            "exhaustiveTypo": true,
            "query": "overcooked",
            "params": "query=overcooked&hitsPerPage=5&page=0&analytics=false&facetFilters=",
            "index": "store_game_en_us",
            "renderingContent": {},
            "processingTimeMS": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all make sure the attribute is added as an [attribute for faceting](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/attributesForFaceting/) .You can either use the API or the Algolia dashboard for that [refer](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/faceting/how-to/declaring-attributes-for-faceting/)

According to the [docs](https://www.algolia.com/doc/guides/managing-results/refine-results/filtering/in-depth/filters-and-facetfilters/#syntax-difference-between-filters-and-facetfilters) `facetFilters` needs to be an array. From what I see you have set it to a string like `facetFilters:"dlcType:-Bundle"` . Instead you need `facetFilters:["dlcType:-Bundle"]`
therefore the `params` will become `"query=overcooked&hitsPerPage=5&page=0&analytics=false&facetFilters=%5B%22dlcType%253A-Bundle%22%5D"`

Also writing the `params` as a string by hand will be cumbersome even with `encodeURI`. Instead you can define the `params` as a Javascript object. An example structure of the requests array is below for a [demo playground](https://codepen.io/cmgchess/pen/oNGmqWE). You can learn the rules for writing the `facetFilters` array [here](https://www.algolia.com/doc/api-reference/api-parameters/facetFilters/)

```html
{
    "requests": [
        {
            "indexName": "bestbuy",
            "params": {
                "query": "app",
                "hitsPerPage": 7,
                "maxValuesPerFacet": 3,
                "page": 0,
                "facets": [
                    "category"
                ],
                "tagFilters": "",
                "facetFilters": [
                    [
                        "category:Cell Phone Cases & Clips",
                        "category:Cases, Armbands & Watchbands"
                    ]
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "indexName": "bestbuy",
            "params": {
                "query": "app",
                "hitsPerPage": 1,
                "maxValuesPerFacet": 3,
                "page": 0,
                "attributesToRetrieve": [],
                "attributesToHighlight": [],
                "attributesToSnippet": [],
                "tagFilters": "",
                "analytics": false,
                "clickAnalytics": false,
                "facets": "category"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Play around with it and look at the network request to get an idea about the `requests` array structure.

Comment: Thank you for your response, sorry the original request param I posted above had "Bundle" but what I was trying to negate was "Individual". 
Anyway, I tried using an array as advised so that I ended up with `"query=overcooked&hitsPerPage=5&page=0&analytics=false&facetFilters=%5B%22dlcType%253A-Individual%22%5D"`. However I get the same issue, dlcType Individual still appears. 

Please note that when I try to facetFilter an array field with an array param, it works as expected, example would be genres, putting facetFilters=["genres:Action"] works but not facetFilters=["dlcType:Individual"]

Comment: is the data saved in your algolia acount. if so check if `dlcType` is set as an `attributesForFaceting` in the index configuration. i suspect that the case is `genres` is set as an attribute for faceting but not `dlcType`

Comment: i believe now what you are getting is if  `facetFilters=["dlcType:Individual"]` you get 0 hits and if  `facetFilters=["dlcType:-Individual"]` you get all the hits

Comment: yes! that is what i'm getting, data is not in my algolia account though. is there a way to set this still?

Comment: Is there a documentation or something of what you are using. Did they specify which fields you can filter from

Comment: Do you have access to an API key. Search only API key wouldn't work. Either admin API key or a key with set settings privilege. If so you can set that attribute as a facet attribute

Comment: no documentation that I know of unfortunately, I got it from a pre-existing API wrapper for the Nintendo eshop - which they built by reverse engineering and it seems that the API key they got was only for search not admin. But that's ok, I'm happy with the info, thank you so much

Comment: Don't know if this is what you are using 
 https://github.com/favna/nintendo-switch-eshop/blob/main/src/lib/getGames/getGamesAmerica.ts#L115 . It has a list of attributes to filter.  Too bad it didn't solve the problem :(

Comment: after visiting the nintendo site i found out from their response that `["genres", "editions", "esrbRating", "franchises", "priceRange", "nsoFeatures", "playerCount", "availability", "corePlatforms", "topLevelFilters", "softwareDeveloper", "softwarePublisher"]` are the fields you can use faceting

Comment: yes, that's what I've been using! Can you please share how did you find which fields can be used for faceting?

Comment: go to https://www.nintendo.com/store/games/?p=1&sort=df with the network tab open. you will find a network request something like `queries?x-algolia-agent=....`  . look at the payload of it and you will see a `facets` array